# Rotated text failure with DVI

Tags: rotating, dvi

I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
 &
\begin{rotate}{60} Property 1 \end{rotate} &
\begin{rotate}{60} Property 2 \end{rotate} &
\begin{rotate}{60} Property 3 \end{rotate} \\ \hline
System 1        &       &       &  X    \\ 
System 2        & X     & X     &  X    \\
System 3        & X &   &  X    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

It works perfectly for the PDF output. However, when I try to use DVI output, it fails. I tried to use `rotatebox` and `sideways` to rotate the text. However all did the same. PDF works great but DVI fails.

I would like to work with DVI for two reasons. (i) Compilation is faster than PDF. (ii) You can see where you left, it opens from the last edit point.

I currently use YAP 2.9, Texnic Center 1.0 Stable release C1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the dvips render mode (YAP->view->Render Method).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Most DVI viewers do not process the PostScript specials which are used by rotation code. Instead, this is left until the DVI to PostScript conversion. As such, you will not readily be able to see the rotation, or indeed any other PostScript material, in the DVI viewer. That means you have two options:

- Accept that you will see material unrotated in the DVI viewer, and wait until you convert to PostScript to see it 'in place'.
- Use direct PDF creation: using a suitable viewer (*e.g.* SumatraPDF) or integrated viewer/editor (*e.g.* TeXworks) you can work much as you do in DVI mode, and can leave the PDF 'open' while compiling (which does not work with Adobe Reader on Windows).