# a small halo symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

One can generate an oval shape using `$\subset\supset$` and adjusting the space in between to make this look like a "halo". Are there any other solutions that would make it look more like an ellipse? I am interested in a smallish symbol that I can use as a sub/superscript or "overscript".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The answer depends on how your symbol should look like. Could you include a picture in your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has the advantage of scaling with `\scriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\halo{{\mkern-.5mu\hstretch{1.8}{\circ}\mkern-2mu}}
\begin{document} 
\( A\mathop{\halo} B \quad 2^\halo \quad \stackon[1pt]{X}{\halo}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what a "halo" is, anyway, something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\halo}{{\subset\mathrel{\mkern-5mu}\supset}}

\begin{document}
\[\halo\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Idea 1

You could rescale a circle.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\halo}{{\scalebox{1}[.5]{\ensuremath{\bigcirc}}}}

\begin{document}

$\overset{\halo}{X}, A_\halo, B^\halo$

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: result]

## Idea 2

Use tikz to draw a circle on a plane inside 3d space.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\newcommand{\halo}{{\tikz[canvas is zx plane at y=0] \draw (0,0) circle (5pt);}}


\begin{document}
    $\overset{\halo}{X}, A_\halo, B^\halo$
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: result]

## Idea 3

Rescale and rotate a circle

### Example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\halo}{{\rotatebox{8}{\scalebox{1}[.3]{\ensuremath{\bigcirc}}}}}

\begin{document}
    $\overset{\halo}{X}, A_\halo, B^\halo$
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Actually I tried to invoke the "tikz" package in my latex file but this does not seem to be part of the standard software provided by our systems people.  Or am I not going about this in the right way?  Don't have too much experience with graphics in latex, mostly formulas :-)

Comment: @katz It should be included with most tex distros. I added a solution that looks similar but won't use tikz.

Comment: Thanks.  The \rotatebox command controls the angle of rotation?

Comment: @katz Yes: `\rotatebox[<optional arguments>]{<angle in degrees>}{<object to rotate>}` For more informations please take a look at the `graphicx` manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks @someonr.  Incidentally, the dvi previewer does not show the true results and displays a plain circle instead. But the pdf generated from dvi displays the ellipses correctly.  Is there anything to be done about the dvi previewer?

Comment: @katz hmm. You can use dvi2ps to convert the dvi file to postscript. The postscript shows up correctly. I'll take another look at this problem.

Comment: similarly I converted it to pdf and was able to see this fine.  I assume it's just that our tex package hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: @katz no, It looks like dvi format has no support for rotating and scaling. That means that ps code will be embedded, but most viewers can't display it correctly. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69282/rotated-text-failure-with-dvihttp://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69282/rotated-text-failure-with-dvi) You could calculate a Bézier curve to use in the picture enviroment http://www.ursoswald.ch/LaTeXGraphics/picture/picture.html#SECTION00044000000000000000.

Comment: OK thanks so it's not just an outdated version.

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}

\Ellipse

\end{document}
```

Or you can use `tikz` and try

```
\tikz \draw (0,0) ellipse (7pt and 3pt);
```